# Problem with building the CGAL 5.0 demo GraphicsView

Tags: cmake, qt5, ubuntu-18.04, cgal

I've installed the CGAL 5.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 box (into my home directory) and tried to build some visualization demos - no success. For example the demo directory `<my CGAL root>/demo/GraphicsView` contains the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
# This is the CMake script for compiling a CGAL application.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.15)
project (GraphicsView_Demo)

if(NOT POLICY CMP0070 AND POLICY CMP0053)
  # Only set CMP0053 to OLD with CMake<3.10, otherwise there is a warning.
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 OLD)
endif()

if(POLICY CMP0071)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0071 NEW)
endif()

find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Qt5)

find_package(Qt5 QUIET COMPONENTS Xml Script OpenGL Svg)

if ( CGAL_FOUND AND CGAL_Qt5_FOUND AND Qt5_FOUND )

  add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
  set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

  add_executable  ( min min.cpp  ${CGAL_Qt5_RESOURCE_FILES} ${CGAL_Qt5_MOC_FILES})

  add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS min )

  target_link_libraries( min PRIVATE
    CGAL::CGAL CGAL::CGAL_Qt5 Qt5::Gui )

  include(${CGAL_MODULES_DIR}/CGAL_add_test.cmake)
  cgal_add_compilation_test(min)
else()

  message(STATUS "NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL and Qt5, and will not be compiled.")

endif()
```

The command `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<my CGAL root> .` generates the output below:

```
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found version "1.65.1")  
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found suitable version "1.65.1", minimum required is "1.48")  
-- Boost include dirs: /usr/include
-- Boost libraries:    
-- libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies:  <CGAL/Qt/*.h> headers cannot be configured.
-- NOTICE: The CGAL_Qt5 library was not configured.
-- NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL and Qt5, and will not be compiled.
...
```

The `<my CGAL root>/include/CGAL/Qt` directory exists and contains a lot of headers - so, the message **"`<CGAL/Qt/*.h>` headers cannot be configured"** looks very suspicious.

What can I try to overcome this problem?

**UPDATE #1.** This is a problem with CGAL 5.0 *only*, and *only* if it's built with the option `CGAL_HEADER_ONLY=OFF`. The culprit is most probably inside CGAL 5.0 `*.cmake` files.

**UPDATE #2.** I used my script (below) to build and install the CGAL 5.0.

```
PKG_NAME=CGAL
PKG_VER=5.0
PKG_FULL_NAME=${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VER}

sudo apt install libgmp-dev
sudo apt install libmpfr-dev
sudo apt install qt5-default
sudo apt install qtscript5-dev

DST_DIR=${HOME}/apps/CGAL/CGAL-5.0
ZIP_DIR=${HOME}/soft

cd /tmp
tar xJvf ${ZIP_DIR}/${PKG_FULL_NAME}.tar.xz
cd ${PKG_FULL_NAME}

mkdir -p build && pushd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${DST_DIR} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCGAL_HEADER_ONLY=OFF ..
make
make install
popd

cp -pr demo ${DST_DIR}
cp -pr examples ${DST_DIR}

cd ..
rm -fr ${PKG_FULL_NAME}
```

Comment: Did you specify CGAL_DIR?

Comment: @MarcGlisse - I tried to use `CGAL_DIR`, and it didn't help. The `find_package` command can find the CGAL installation using the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` only. However, the presence of the `Qt5` in the `COMPONENTS` list gives me this error. Did you try to reproduce the error?

Comment: You say that you are not using the header only mode. Did you build CGAL, then ?
If you really want to not use the header-only mode, you need to build the CGAL library with the option WITH_Qt5=ON, which should be the default IIRC.

Comment: @mgimeno - Yes, I've built the CGAL 5.0. This combination of options (`CGAL_HEADER_ONLY=OFF` and `WITH_CGAL_Qt5=ON`) is what that gives me that error (`<CGAL/Qt/*.h`). And you are right - the `WITH_CGAL_Qt5=ON` option is default one, I tried with and without it, and result was the same. So, the CGAL online manual is correct about that

Comment: I don't reproduce your bug on my Ubuntu. Did you provide CGAL's build directory as CGAL_DIR cmake variable ? Did you provide Qt5 while configuring CGAL before building ?

Comment: @mgimeno - yes and yes. Is your CGAL 5.0 installation header-only?

Comment: Yes. What is the output of your configuration of the lib CGAL ? There should be some explanation over there on why libCGAL_Qt5 is not configured.

Comment: @mgimeno - I'm getting only that three lines which I've posted in my question. What cmake debugging options do you want me to add to get more explanations?

Comment: That is strange, because `-- NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL and Qt5, and will not be compiled.`  really looks like an output from a demo, not the lib itself. The cmake command you provided uses a relative path. Is it the one to the root dir of CGAL ?

Comment: @mgimeno - I think you will be able to reproduce this error if you rebuild the CGAL 5.0 with header only mode switched OFF

Comment: I did and I do not reproduce. If you switch OFF the header only mode, it means you have to build the lib before you build the tests, example, demos or anything that will link to cgal. If you build it in CGAL/build, then CGAL/build is the path you will have to give as CGAL_DIR when you configure the demo.

Comment: Also, how did you install CGAL ? Did you use the package manager or downloaded a release ?

Comment: @HEKTO Please show use `grep CGAL_DIR CMakeCache`, so that we can verify which CGAL you tried to compile with. Maybe you have the Ubuntu `libcgal-dev` installed, but not `libcgal-qt5-dev`, and that could explain the message `<CGAL/Qt/*.h> headers cannot be configured.`

Comment: @lrineau - no, I don't have any Ubuntu-provided CGAL installations. After I issue command `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/apps/CGAL/current ..` (in the `build` directory) the command `grep CGAL_DIR CMakeCache.txt` gives me `CGAL_DIR:PATH=/home/hekto/apps/CGAL/current/lib/cmake/CGAL`

Comment: @mgimeno - I've added a script, which I used to install the CGAL 5.0 - please see my updated question

Comment: @lrineau - I did some more investigation, so please look at the `CGAL_SetupCGAL_Qt5Dependencies.cmake` script, line 39. It looks like it is the place where the process got stuck

Comment: Thank you for that script. Using this recipe I still cannot reproduce your exact error, but I see you also need to install the package libqt5svg5-dev in order to build CGAL_qt5.

Comment: @HEKTO I can reproduce your error. The issue is the value of `CGAL_GRAPHICSVIEW_PACKAGE_DIR` in the installed `CGALConfig.cmake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks for your patience in reporting the bug.)

There is indeed a logic error in CGAL-5.0, when installed in non-header-only mode. I will issue a fix soon. And a new release CGAL-5.0.1.

Can you please try with this patch?

```
diff --git a/Installation/cmake/modules/CGALConfig_install.cmake.in b/Installation/cmake/modules/CGALConfig_install.cmake.in
index 873fa8c6a9e..cb51524dcfa 100644
--- a/Installation/cmake/modules/CGALConfig_install.cmake.in
+++ b/Installation/cmake/modules/CGALConfig_install.cmake.in
@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@ set(CGAL_ImageIO_USE_ZLIB                 "@CGAL_ImageIO_USE_ZLIB@" )
 set(CGAL_VERSION "${CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CGAL_MINOR_VERSION}.${CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION}")

 set(CGAL_USE_FILE "${CGAL_MODULES_DIR}/UseCGAL.cmake" )
-set(CGAL_GRAPHICSVIEW_PACKAGE_DIR "${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIRS}/CGAL/" CACHE INTERNAL "Directory containing the GraphicsView package")
+set(CGAL_GRAPHICSVIEW_PACKAGE_DIR "${CGAL_INSTALL_PREFIX}" CACHE INTERNAL "Directory containing the GraphicsView package")

 if ( CGAL_FIND_REQUIRED )
   set( CHECK_CGAL_COMPONENT_MSG_ON_ERROR TRUE        )
```

The patch applies to CGAL-5.0/ with `patch -p2`. Once the patch is applied, please reinstall CGAL.

Update: here is the pull-request, in Github: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/4459

Comment: All works now - I was happy to contribute a little-little-bit to your remarkable project